# How to make a MIB configurations file accessible by three different libraries?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, lib, mib, snmp-trap

**So my question is based around the scenario :**

- I have three snmp libraries that i built myself i.e. one in nodejs, one in c++, one in java.
- There is a project that responds to all of these 3 libs snmp queries. (In this we can add new configurations to the MIB file)
- I have a MIB file with all the configurations and mapping of query, queryname and their oid's.

**The problem is that MIB file needs to be accessed by all three libraries quite frequently.**

- How do i keep the file synchronized between three libraries while the project keeps on adding new configurations.

The summary is how do i keep that file synchronized and make it a single source of truth used by all three libs and am able to update that single source of truth.

Comment: Is it a question on source code management? Assume your libraries are stored in separate Git repos, you can store the MIB document in its own repo and add to the library repos as submodule.

Comment: Yes it is, and i like the submodule idea.